# My regex not working when the value is empty

Tags: regex

Below is my regex used in a jQuery function I just want allow A-Z, a-b, 0-9, few special characters and space.

This is working but it doesn't detected the space what is wrong with this. I know there are many I tried almost all of them but didn't work.

```
regX = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\'.-\\s]+$");
```

**UPDATE:** specials are ', . = and space. The expectation from this is to allow something like this,

> My mother's father, mom and sister = is bad.

The text filed is not always need to be filled it can have a empty text value.

Comment: what all are the special characters you need to allow ?

Comment: could you edit and insert an example of what you expect by this reg exp?

Comment: Just tried and it seems working, it matches `-- --` and `12ad'. -` strings.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape backslash inside the character class, i.e. `\s` alone would suffice.

Comment: Wait, you say you need to match `=`, then you need to add it to the character class. Just use `regX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\s=-]+$/` (not sure you need the hyphen, it is not within the UPDATE chars). Looks like a typo question.

Comment: The given regular expression is detecting space. Are you looking for a regex which blocks a space ??

Comment: if you need only '.,== special characters then use this regX = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9'.,=s]+$");

Comment: Ok I'll test it out I don't know why I got the down votes but will try @ArunprasanthKV's suggestion I think it's due to the emty value getting submitted by the empty text box.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/p1em7gmq/  I have provided a jsfiddle example for the same

Comment: I didn't down voted you but you are getting down votes because your question  wasn't  clear.

Comment: Oh ok, your regex works and the problem was not with my regex it's the empty text box I use the regex like this `!regX.test($('#remarks').val())` when the value is empty it just pop's the message saying not allowed.

Comment: is your issue got resolved
?

Comment: Yes your comment helped but the main issue was the empty value which was not detected by the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below regex

```
regX = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9'. ,=s]+$")
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/p1em7gmq/)  Fiddle